# How can I overlay the captured timestamp onto a video using ffmpeg in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS format?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-editing

I am trying to overlay a timestamp (date and time when frame captured) on video frames for a stored video file using ffmpeg.

This succeeds in displaying time in seconds since the beginning of the video:

`ffmpeg -i in.webm -filter_complex "drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/arial.ttf: text='%{pts \:flt}': x=100 : y=50 : box=1" -c:a copy out.webm`

The [documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawtext-1) indicates that the `pts` can also take a `gmtime` argument to print out the date and time,

> pts
>
> The timestamp of the current frame. It can take up to three arguments.
>
> The first argument is the format of the timestamp; it defaults to flt for seconds as a decimal number with microsecond accuracy; hms stands for a formatted [-]HH:MM:SS.mmm timestamp with millisecond accuracy. gmtime stands for the timestamp of the frame formatted as UTC time; localtime stands for the timestamp of the frame formatted as local time zone time.
>
> The second argument is an offset added to the timestamp.
>
> If the format is set to localtime or gmtime, a third argument may be supplied: a strftime() format string. By default, YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS format will be used.

But when I try to use
`ffmpeg -i in.webm -filter_complex "drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/arial.ttf: text='%{pts \:gmtime}': x=100 : y=50 : box=1" -c:a copy out.webm`
I get the error `Invalid format 'gmtime'`.

```
ffmpeg version 2.8.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8 (SUSE Linux)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib64 --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --incdir=/usr/include/ffmpeg --extra-cflags='-fmessage-length=0 -grecord-gcc-switches -O2 -Wall -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector -funwind-tables -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -g' --optflags='-fmessage-length=0 -grecord-gcc-switches -O2 -Wall -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector -funwind-tables -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -g' --disable-htmlpages --enable-pic --disable-stripping --enable-shared --disable-static --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-gpl --disable-openssl --enable-avresample --enable-libcdio --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcelt --enable-libcdio --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-pic --enable-pthreads --enable-vaapi --enable-vdpau --disable-decoder=dca --enable-libdcadec --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-version3 --enable-x11grab
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'in.webm':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
  Duration: 00:01:43.32, start: 0.007000, bitrate: 504 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: vp8, yuv420p, 480x640, SAR 1:1 DAR 3:4, 1k fps, 1k tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : Video
    Stream #0:1: Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
[libvpx-vp9 @ 0x2083580] v1.3.0
[webm @ 0x20823a0] Codec for stream 1 does not use global headers but container format requires global headers
Output #0, webm, to 'out.webm':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: vp9 (libvpx-vp9), yuv420p, 480x640 [SAR 1:1 DAR 3:4], q=-1--1, 200 kb/s, 1k fps, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.60.100 libvpx-vp9
    Stream #0:1: Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, stereo (default)
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (vp8) -> drawtext
  drawtext -> Stream #0:0 (libvpx-vp9)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[Parsed_drawtext_0 @ 0x2084ea0] Invalid format 'gmtime'
    Last message repeated 1 times
Past duration 0.999992 too large
[Parsed_drawtext_0 @ 0x2084ea0] Invalid format 'gmtime'
    Last message repeated 28 times
```

How do I get the overlayed text to display the UTC time in a YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS format?

Comment: It's used like this: `text='%{gmtime}'`, but that will display current time formatted as UTC. I'm not sure if that's what you want or not.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard No unfortunately that is not what I am looking for, I am looking for the time the frame was captured. I have included the section of the documentation that describes what I was hoping to do.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a start time as a Unix Epoch integer (1507046400 below) and alternatively inform the date-time format (%d-%m-%Y %T below):

```
text='%{pts\:gmtime\:1507046400\:%d-%m-%Y %T}'
```

Comment: Informing a start time is useful when you are marking a video that was recorded in (or contains images from) the past.

Answer (score 3):

'gmtime' seems to work now.

I'm using this string:

```
"drawtext=fontfile=FreeSerif.ttf:fontcolor=white:text='%{pts\\:gmtime}:fontsize=14'[out]"
```

I use it from c++ code so you may need to escape it differently.

Alternatively you could use a combination of static text for the date and **'hms'** with offset parameter to rebuild the time in whatever time zone you need:

```
"drawtext=fontfile=FreeSerif.ttf:fontcolor=white:text='1970-01-01 %{pts\\:HMS\\:7200}:fontsize=14'[out]"
```